# JQuery AJAX call function running twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

EDIT: Unfortunately the answers and suggestions have not quite fixed the issue. I may have to switch to a "view more posts" button rather than using the scroll as I see this as the problem. Would be great to finally get a solution to this though as I can't find one anywhere.

My solution was to add a timeout event. Terrible and dirty. this:

```
complete: function (data) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#loading-posts").fadeOut("fast");
        $isFetchingNotes = false;
    }, 1000);
}
```

I written a custom blog for my website. As the user scrolls, older posts appear and load automatically through JQuery AJAX. This is working - however, it appears to be fetching the data 2, 3 or 4 more times than I want it to. I only want it to fetch the data once in fact. 
So I put an "is running" type variable in, but that's not working either and it still fetches the data more than once and duplicates the post. Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

    var $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    var $docHeight = $(document).height();
    var $winHeight = $(window).height();
    var $lastPost = ($(".note-area:last").attr("id") - 1);

    if($scroll === $docHeight - $winHeight) {

        if(!$isFetchingNotes) {

            var $isFetchingNotes = true;

            $("div.more-posts").show();
            $("#loading-posts-gif").fadeIn("slow");

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'loadnotes.php" ?>',
                data: { 
                    'lastPost': $lastPost
                },
                cache:true,
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data) {

                        $('div#post-area').append(data);
                        $('div.more-posts').hide();

                    } else {
                        $('div.more-posts').replaceWith("<h4>-- End of notes --</h4>");
                    }
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loading-posts").fadeOut("fast");
                }   
            }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
                $('div.more-posts').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
            });

            $isFetchingNotes = false;

        } // End if $isfetchingnotes

    } // End if scroll load point

}); // End onscroll event
```

Can anyone please shed some light on why it may be trying to keep fetching the data despite the $isFetchingNotes variable being set to true? Thank you!

Comment: It's async, so setting a flag, and then unsetting it again below the ajax call, does nothing. You need to unset the flag inside the complete handler.

Comment: @adaneo Additionally, every call to the `scroll` method has its own "instance" of `$isFetchingNotes`, I believe. Correct me if I am mistaking.

Comment: @Derija93 i had a fear that this may be the case. changing it to the complete handler did nothing.

Comment: Or use any old deferred object, and escape callback hell.

Comment: @Incognito hey there - could you please elaborate on your point? Thanks

Comment: @30secondstosam Instead of using nested callbacks that get deeper and deeper indented you can use a deferred object to get out of the need to keep providing a huge chain of callbacks. Deferred objects and promises are cool, and they really help turn code like this into clean, readable, and manageable code (especially when you scale up complexity).

Comment: hi @Incognito - i'll try that out. I'm a OO PHP developer so I should really be writing OO JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Razzak got half of it. You need the `$isFetchingNotes` variable outside the function, and you need to not return it to false until AFTER the loading is complete (in the `complete` callback). Here it is:

```
  var $isFetchingNotes = false;

    $(window).scroll(function(){

        var $scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        var $docHeight = $(document).height();
        var $winHeight = $(window).height();
        var $lastPost = ($(".note-area:last").attr("id") - 1);

        if($scroll > $docHeight - $winHeight) {

            if(!$isFetchingNotes) {

                $isFetchingNotes = true;

                $("div.more-posts").show();
                $("#loading-posts-gif").fadeIn("slow");

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: 'loadnotes.php" ?>',
                    data: { 
                        'lastPost': $lastPost
                    },
                    cache:true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        if(data) {

                            $('div#post-area').append(data);
                            $('div.more-posts').hide();

                        } else {
                            $('div.more-posts').replaceWith("<h4>-- End of notes --</h4>");
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        $("#loading-posts").fadeOut("fast");
                        $isFetchingNotes = false;
                    }   
                }).error(function (event, jqXHR, ajaxSettings, thrownError) {
                    $('div.more-posts').html("<h2>Could not retrieve data</h2>");
                });


            } // End if $isfetchingnotes

        } // End if scroll load point

    }); // End onscroll event
```

Also, I'd recommend not having the condition be where `$scroll` is *exactly* that position, as it won't fire for each pixel of scrolling. You're better off putting:

```
if($scroll > $docHeight - $winHeight) { ...
```

instead of:

```
if($scroll === $docHeight - $winHeight) { ...
```

Comment: Hi Mike - thanks very much for your input . It's funny, before I read this I did indeed put the > rather than === :).

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the `$isFetchingNotes` variable outside `scroll` function:

```
var $isFetchingNotes = false;
$(window).scroll(function(){
...
}
```

change it to false again after ajax has completed:

```
complete: function(){
    $isFetchingNotes = false;
    ...
}
```

Comment: That is definitely a better performance. It seems to work and then I managed to break it by continuously scrolling down (this code is fired at the bottom of the page much like Facebook). So close. Still not perfect though..